# How to parse for length of functions in a python module?

Tags: python, static-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree

Python modules can be parsed with `ast.parse`.

With the module object returned, nodes can be iterated and attributes like `lineno` and `name` can be accessed.

Currently, the way I use to determine the length (number of lines) of a function is to find the node X that corresponds to the function, and get the node Y right after it, then `Y.lineno - X.lineno` is the length (possibly with blank lines included).

But this method is not fast enough to me. Is there any tools that I can use to do this kind of static analysis?

Comment: Have you looked at [`inspect.getsource`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource)?

Comment: @BrenBarn I think to use `inspect.getsource` I'll have to actually evaluate the module and get the function object.

Comment: That is true.  Do you not want to do that?  If not, why not?  You might want to explain more in your question about any constraints you have.

Comment: Not "fast enough"?  How long does it take, and why do you consider that to be slow?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ".end_lineno", it returns the line that the function ends.
Hope it helps you!